# Codeigniter Session->userdata is null

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

My project has several views which draw values out of the session->userdata array.
the whole project works flawlessly on my development machine, but when I copied the project up to a server, I find that $this->session->userdata is null.

This is the code which inserts some values into the session->userdata array:
It is called in the Controller.

```
    $sessionArray = array(
            'web_id' => $id,
            'paperId' => $paperId,
            'prelimId' => $prelimId,
            'intakeId' => $intakeId,
            'finalId' => $finalId,
     );

     $this->session->set_userdata($sessionArray);
```

In the view file I call

```
var_dump($this->session->userdata);
```

The value returned is null.  As I mentioned before, the array is NOT null on my development computer (running WAMP). Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are you sure cookies are being properly set on the live server?

Comment: If this appears after a redirection, check my answer here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105321/codeigniter-session-destroy-after-redirect/65700536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105321/codeigniter-session-destroy-after-redirect/65700536)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to retrieve all session data as an ASSOC array, you could use the `all_userdata()` method. *(Take a look at CodeIgniter [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html))*,

You can write that within your ***Controller*** and send the returned value to the view, as follows:

```php
$data['userdata'] = $this->session->all_userdata();
$this->load->view('your/view.php', $data); // use $userdata in the view
```

**Note:** Using the session library directly inside the *views* [may cause unexpected problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606594/codeigniter-session-hanging). Try managing your sessions in the *Controller* instead of the *View*.

Comment: Followed your advice, the problem gets stranger.  Now when my view loads, `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());` results in completely blank page.  Error reporting is turned on in Codeigniter, and there is no exit statement following the var_dump.  As in I stated in my post above, this problem only exists on the web server. My development machine just shows me an array of useful information.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Try [this approach](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/178904/#849526), it seems there's something wrong with configs.

Comment: all_userdata() has been removed from latest codeigniter session library.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting here in answer block first of all.......... Where you are assigning those values to $sessionArray. What i mean is in model or controller or in view file.

Are you calling var_dump($this->session->userdata) in view file.

Why don't you call that in controller and pass that as an array to view file via controller.

try like this in controller i will get user details in $login array from database for suppose when i submit username and password.

I will send those details to session array like this in model file

```
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in_user', $login);
```

after that in controller if i want use user name from session array i will use like below.

```
$logged_in = $this->session->userdata("logged_in_user");
$model=array();
$model['logged_in_user']=$logged_in[0];
```

Once after i assigned to $model array i like to use that in view file so i will pass that $model array to view file from controller like this

```
$this->load->view('view_file_path',$model);
```

You can use that array in view file how ever you want from passed array.

Comment: I think you are advising me to pass data from controller. Thanks.

Comment: yeah that will make easy for u